# JTextField constant text when disabled

Tags: java, swing, subclass, jtextfield

I'm looking for some smart way to solve my problem. I didn't find any solution in the Web. Actually I would ask you for any tip, clue...

I've got a dialog with many JTextFields. They represent some object's state (let's call it "model").
There are some cases in which some of these fields should be disabled. Despite the fact, that "model" contains values for these fields I do not want to display them (they are irrelevant). So, I would like to set  "n/A" value in each disabled field (always when it's disabled).

The only idea I have is to create `CustomJTextBox extends JTextBox` and override the `setText()` method :

```
class CustomTextField extends JTextField {
    //... constructors
    @Override
    public void setText(String s){
        if(!this.isEnabled()){
            super.setText("n/A");
        } else {
            super.setText(s);
        }
    }
}
```

But it has lots of weak points :D

- It works only when using setText()
- It will not work if I use CustomTextFIeld(String s) constructor - this constructor shouldn't be available which is not intuitive
- and probably maaany more...

I guess it should exist some other approch... could you give any tips?

Comment: Why not `setVisible(false)` instead of `setEnable(false)` ?

Comment: Don't extend Swing components. Just change the text the fields display, using a method which disables the text fields AND changes their text to n/A at the same time.

Comment: @Nizil I agree, but... customer's requirenment :D

Comment: @JBNizet That's exactly what I currenty have... I thouhgt it exists any other, smarter way ;)

Comment: I doubt that _extending_ a swing component is a customer requirement - it's your suboptimal solution :-) It's the task of the (presentation) model to provide both enablement and special text as needed by the view.

Comment: @kleopatra Customer's requirenment doesn't allow me to write "setVisible(false)" as Nizil proposed :P Extending a swing component is definitely not required :P

Answer (score 2):

Instead of extending a `JTextComponent`, use a [static factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), discussed [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/creating-and-destroying-java-objects-par/208403883). In the factory, add a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) that enforces your requirement.